# Associate a JList with radio buttons

Tags: java, swing, jlist, jradiobutton

I got a `JList` which I fill with mesure types. The user can fill it by select mesure type from a combo box and fill the list. I have also 5 characteristics radio buttons which normally set the characteristic of the mesure, so for each mesure type, there is 5 different options.

I draw a schematic of the window:

```
+-------------+
|Mesuretype1  |
|Mesuretype2  |
|Mesuretype3  |
+-------------+
°option 1 °option 2 °option 3 °option 4
```

Is this possible,  and is there a manner to associate the list with the radio buttons, and save the state of them (like the first mesure have only option 1, the second option 3, e...)?

To finish the program, after having choose different mesures and the options associated, the user clicks finish and all data is saved to database.

I work with Java Swing.

Comment: By *"mesure types"* DYM "measure types"? The second I don't understand, but as to the first, I've not even heard the word 'mesure' before.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would recommend not using a `JList` for this.

Use a `JPanel` inside a `JScrollPane`. That panel can have a `new GridLayout(0, 1)` set, and then add to it almost as many panels as you want, where each one will hold the *mesure* type name and the radio buttons for that *mesure*. This way you can scroll horizontally (if there are too many radio buttons for a *mesure*) or vertically (if there are too many *mesures*), but this way will help you also maintain the state of each *mesure* (via holding references to its radio buttons).

In comparison to the `JList` approach, you will probably have to mess with adding a `MouseListener` to locate which radio button the user selected, or mess with the `JList`'s UI.

Follows sample code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class Main {
    public static class MesurePanel extends JPanel {
        private final ButtonGroup group;

        public MesurePanel(final String mesure,
                           final String... options) { //Behaves like a "normal" array of options.
            super(new BorderLayout());
            super.add(new JLabel(mesure, JLabel.CENTER), BorderLayout.LINE_START);
            final JPanel lineEnd = new JPanel(); //FlowLayout...
            group = new ButtonGroup();
            for (final String option: options) {
                final JRadioButton radio = new JRadioButton(option);
                group.add(radio);
                lineEnd.add(radio);
            }
            super.add(lineEnd, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        final int mesureCount = 10; //Startup setting...

        //Create mesures:
        final ArrayList<String> mesures = new ArrayList<>(mesureCount);
        for (int i = 0; i < mesureCount; ++i)
            mesures.add("MesureType " + (i + 1));

        //Create options for each mesure:
        final JPanel contents = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1)); //1 column, any number of rows...
        mesures.forEach(mesure -> contents.add(new MesurePanel(mesure, "Option 1", "Option 2", "Option N")));

        final JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(contents);
        scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 200));

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("List of MesureTypes.");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(scroll);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

and screenshot:

[image: Panel simulating JList]

Answer (score 0):

From your question, the most I am gathering is that you want a way to associate one "MesureType" with only one option from the radio button.

By utilizing [the Hashmap util](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), you can map the two together, so that a MesureType is associated with a selection from the radio buttons. For example:

HashMap map = new HashMap();
map.put( *your list*.getSelectedValue(), *the selected button value*);